# Uploading Chrome Extension - Error: Failed to process your item

Tags: google-chrome-extension, upload

When uploading my zip file using the Developer Dashboard, I'm getting the following error:

```
An error occurred: Failed to process your item.

Can not process the manifest file.,Can not process the message.json file.,Can not process the key.pem file.,Chrome Web Store system error, please try again later.
```

I've followed 3 different tutorials (2 on extensions, and 1 on uploading to the Developer Dashboard) that I found on creating an extension on Googles' site. None of them say to create a *message.json* so I didn't create one (not sure why its telling me it can't process it). There is also no *key.pem* file, as they said do not generate this file and don't include it - as it will be generated when you upload it.

It says try again later, but I've tried several weeks now with no luck.

Currently, I'm exploring if my zip file is generated "funny" from 7-zip.  I'd use the built in windows zip once I get that working again - however it seems corrupted.

My manifest file is in the root folder, and and the extension works in developer mode on my chrome. I've quadruple checked that the JSON is valid as well.

The extension works great for me, but fails the upload process.

How do I get past this step of the process?

Comment: My manifest file is in the root folder, and and the extension works in developer mode on my chrome.  I've quadruple checked that the json is valid as well.   Or do you mean pull the manifest file outside the root and change all the directories inside the manifest?  FWIW - all files are in the root directory.  Its just a simple html, js, and png files.

Comment: Sure:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=87686357027643346615

Comment: Same error, no directories.  --I've tried that before as well.

Comment: Yes, here is the new zip file- http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=19483824858430265479

The extension works great for me... are you saying its different if I publish it?

Comment: I knew it was 7-zip doing something funny.  That was it, changed it to deflate instead of deflate64.  Thank you so much!

Side note:  Your right, I forgot to remove the start() during my experiments.  Thanks for noticing it.

Side note:  I first tried the deflate 'with directory' per my first attempts, it worked, thankfully since this is how the tutorial had me do it.

Comment: FYI: All information relevant to answering the question should be [edit]ed into the question itself, not just in comments. It's OK to put it in comments, but it is more important to put such info into the question. Comments should be considered to be temporary (even though they usually stick around for years). If *you* choose to only put the information in either the question or comments, then it should be in the question. You can put a note in comments with an `@` followed by the user name (e.g. `@Makyen` for me) with something like "I added the information you requested to the question."

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure manifest.json is in the root of the zip archive (not inside any directory)
2. Use the standard `deflate` zipping method in 7-zip, not anything fancy like `deflate64`

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this was:

In the 7-Zip settings, I was using the compression method Deflate64, I changed it to Deflate and it the zip file was accepted.  Thanks to @wOxxOm

I probably wouldn't have had this problem but my windows built in zip is currently corrupted and used 7zip to make a zip file.

Comment: Thanks.  The only difference this time for me was using 7Zip, I would never have caught that without your post!